# Regional Proximity UI

Tags: user-interface, regional, proximity

I'm developing a UI (AJAX-enabled; LAMP server) which will allow a user to designate regions in which a company operates. A "region" in this case may be a state (if dealing with the US) a province (Canada), or entire country (everyone else).

As there are 195 countries in the world, I would like to avoid a multi-select box or list of checkboxes. In the workflow leading to this particular screen, the user will have already entered the full address of the company, so I have a starting region to work from.

Since the majority of companies only operate out of their own region, and those covering multiple regions tend not to branch out too far, I am considering displaying the list of regions gradually based on proximity. I realize at some point (I'm using 3 passes for now) the full list will need to be displayed; I'm just trying to delay the user from reaching that point as it's a definite edge case.

[Here is a PNG mockup that explains this concept a bit more clearly](http://mark-hurd.com/temp/region-proximity.png). (196kb)

**Questions:**

- What suggestions do you have for the actual form interaction? This has not been presented to representative end users yet, but I'm open to all suggestions during the prototyping stage.
- Do you think 'rolling up' US states and/or Canadian provinces between transitions will negatively affect the user's spatial memory?

  - More clearly: after the 3rd pass, the company will operate in every US state - so convert those 50 inputs into one.
- Are there any existing applications that have utilized this approach to use as a baseline or demo?
- And, since I know my developer will want to know - what would be the easiest way to store each region's proximity? Lat/long of the center? Lat/long of each corner of a 'bounding box' (more accurate)? I'm assuming we will end up writing some proximity calculations based on the lat/long of the company's actual address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting users to read the map in order to know what list of checkboxes to go to? If your users have than level of geographic ability, then it’s less work for them to select the regions directly from the map, rather than have them make the map-to-Proximity-Level cognitive transfer, followed by a Proximity-Level-to-region transfer.

If some users do not have that level geographic expertise (you may be surprised how many Americans cannot find their own state on a US map), then I’d try, perhaps in addition to the map, no more than two lists, one proximal (the default) with regions close to the home address, and one exhaustive. I can’t see users with weak geographic abilities being be able to handle multiple arbitrary levels of proximity. People who can’t read maps well are not going to able to estimate the proximity level of one region to another. So the idea is to try a proximal list and if that doesn’t work, then forget about proximity and go exhaustive –don’t send your users wandering among proximity levels looking for Idaho (“I swear it’s near Indiana”).

By default, show the proximal list with regions likely to satisfy most of your users based on research of your likely clients. A “more” button displays the exhaustive list. Both lists should be sorted alphabetically, except first subdivide the exhaustive list into States of the US, Provinces & Territories of Canada, and Country (which includes the US (all) and Canada (all)).

You can provide some command buttons to select multiple regions (e.g., “All 48 contiguous US states, All of South America), allowing users to de-select some regions afterward. For this reason, I wouldn’t roll anything up until the user commits the input.

As an example of someone using a map plus list (all in HTML, no less), see http://justaddwater.dk/2007/12/21/map-with-positions-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

I am not really clear what it is that you are trying to achieve from the current UI (are you looking for branch offices? other companies? etc?)

I am not a big fan of using pure geographical proximity to define regions. For example, if one company operates in NYC, it could have an office in NJ which could well be as far as the moon. On the other hand, for a company in anchorage, an office in Vancouver could still be within the region. Unfortunately, state boundaries are fairly meaningless too. For example, I live in western PA, and can tell you that while Pittsburgh and Philly are in the same state, they could be different countries for all that matters, and most companies have offices in each.

If your project is lamp based, why not just let a user click a point on the map, and based on that ask him what he means (e.g., nearest city, entire county, entire state, entire country?. If you then need to define the entire region, you can perhaps use some sort of a grab tool to click or delineate all the other regions that could be part of it?

Either way, present your offices as pushpins on the map, and then maybe have a list on the side the way that standard google maps handles searches.

It may be a lot of work, but if it's an important form, users may prefer that over manual text entry or selections from a list.

Comment: The UI is basically saying, "Company X sells products in regions 1,2,3. Company Y sells in 2,3,4." My interest in proximity is based on data showing MOST companies sell only in their region/ nearby regions. There are exceptions to that rule, so all options have to remain accessible at some point.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding something. Is this an input form or an output form? It looked like an input form to me, so the user is telling you where they're selling stuff, not you telling them where other companies are selling.